# Filling empty area and removing protruding areas in an area in image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to fill some empty areas and remove protruding areas to make the image smoother. But it works to an extent only. The largest contour needs to be made smoother. 
    Input Image:

[image: Input image]

```
import os
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

Dd = cv2.imread('images/input.png', 0)

kernel = np.ones((6,6),np.uint8)

DdErode = 1;
DdDilate = 1;

Dd = cv2.erode(Dd,kernel,iterations = DdErode)
Dd = cv2.dilate(Dd,kernel,iterations = DdDilate)

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(Dd, cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

maxArea = 0;
position = 0;
maxPosition =0;
for cont in contours :
    area = cv2.contourArea(cont);
    if area > maxArea :
        maxArea = area;
        maxPosition = position;

    position = position + 1;

# print (maxArea);

epsilon = 0.001*cv2.arcLength(contours[maxPosition],True)

epsilon = 0.001*cv2.arcLength(contours[maxPosition],True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[maxPosition],epsilon,True)

cv2.drawContours(Dd, [approx], -1, (255, 255, 0), -1)

cv2.imwrite('images/output.jpg', Dd)
```

The output of the program

[image: Output]

But I was trying for something without the dents and protruding parts as below. Is there a way to do it?

[image: Desired]

Answer (score 0):

You're using a square kernel, which will give your shapes square corners. Using a circular one will give smoother, rounded corners. Also, using a kernel with an even number of pixels each side will cause your shape to shift slightly. Odd numbers are better for kernel sizes.

Also, the more iterations you use, the more smoothing you get. If you use too many iterations, it will start to remove important details. So, start with 1 iteration, and increase iterations until you are happy.

I got this result using a 7x7 circular kernel, 5 iterations of erosion followed by 5 iterations of dilation:

[image]

Code:

```
Dd = cv2.imread('images/input.png', 0)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(7,7))
Dd = cv2.erode(Dd,kernel,iterations = 5)
Dd = cv2.dilate(Dd,kernel,iterations = 5)

cv2.imwrite('images/output.png', Dd)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Chungzuwalla. I tried the approach you have mentioned. The problem here is, this is actually reducing the size of the area by at least 10% more. For my requirement, i need to keep the area as much as possible in the output. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you are removing protruding parts, the area of the result will necessarily be different to the original.  You could try making the kernel smaller (eg. 3x3), or using fewer iterations, to get your required tolerance at the cost of less smoothing. But if your input images are unknown, there may be no fixed parameters which work, so you may need an adaptive solution.  For example: apply a few rounds of erosion, then apply dilation one round at a time, counting the number of lit pixels after each round, until the count is as close as possible to the number of pixels you started with.